# Java check if java native object don't have default value, or whether it is instantiated or not

Tags: java, object, reflection

I have to check whether following `non-null object` should not have default value

1. if Object is `String` or `Char`(primitive) then it shouldn't be `null` or empty
2. if Object is `Integer` or `int`(primitive) then it shouldn't be `0` (zero)
3. if Object is `Boolean` or `boolean`(primitive) then it shouldn't be `false`
4. if Object is any `Collection` then it shouldn't be `empty` or `null`
5. if Object is any `Map` then it shouldn't be `empty` or `null`

I have to store all other `Object` into `List<String> usedTags = new ArrayList<>();` to send it back.

```
private List<String> isUsedTag(Method method, Object objName) {
    List<String> usedTags = new ArrayList<>();
    if (objName != null && (((objName instanceof Integer) && (!isNullorZero((Integer) objName)))
                    || ((objName instanceof String) && (!Util.isAnyNullOrEmpty((String) objName)) && !((String)objName).equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
                    || ((objName instanceof Boolean) && ((Boolean) objName))
                    || ((objName instanceof Object) && !(objName instanceof Boolean))
                    || ((objName instanceof List) && !Util.isEmpty((List)objName))
                    || ((objName.getClass().isPrimitive()) && (Integer.valueOf((int)objName) != 0))
            )) {
        usedTags.add(method.getName());
    } 
    return usedTags;
}
```

And checking whether the `Integer` object is '0' method is as

```
public static boolean isNullorZero(Integer i){
    return 0 == ( i == null ? 0 : i);
}
```

Using this code my all conditions aren't getting satisfied :( , can someone help?

Comment: This is about reviewing running code and should be asked at [codereview.se]

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/233408/214372 done! once I get the satisfactory answer, I'll delete this question 

Comment: Why are you checking strings against `"0"`? That doesn’t match your description. Further, your description does not preclude `null` for `Integer` or `Boolean`. But actually, it’s not clear why you mention “should not be `null`” for all other types, when your description started with “following non-null object”, in other words, assumes the object reference to be non-`null` even prior to the check?

Comment: Solved! answered my own question, let me know if this can be further optimised. Yes, in my question have many silly mistakes, sorry 

Answer (score 0):

Finally I'm able to achieve all desired outcomes, thank you guys.

I have collected all available Objects beforehand in the `private Set<Object> availableObj = new HashSet<Object>();` to determine the given object is known to my framework.

```
private List<String> isUsedTag(Method method, Object objName) {
    List<String> usedTags = new ArrayList<>();
    if (isWellKNownObj(objName) && !isEmptyCollection(objName) && !isEmptyMap(objName)
           && !isEmptyStrOrZeroInt(objName) && isTrue(objName)) {
        usedTags.add(method.getName());
    } 
    return usedTags;
}

private boolean isWellKNownObj(Object objName) {
    return (objName != null && availableObj.contains(objName));
}

private boolean isEmptyCollection(Object objName) {
    return ((objName instanceof Collection<?>) && Util.isEmpty((Collection<?>) objName));
}

private boolean isEmptyMap(Object objName) {
    return ((objName instanceof Map<?,?>) && Util.isEmpty((Map<?,?>) objName));
}

public boolean isEmptyStrOrZeroInt(Object objName) {
    return (((objName instanceof Integer) && TestngUtil.isNullorZero((Integer) objName))
            || ((objName instanceof String) && Util.isNullOrEmpty((String) objName)));
}

public boolean isTrue(Object objName) {
    return ((objName instanceof Boolean) ? ((Boolean) objName): true);
}
```